# Nikon D750 + Nikkor 18-35mm - How to enable full autofocus?

Tags: nikon, autofocus

I recently got this powerful duet (before I had Pentax K-r), sadly I can call myself a total beginner even I used dslr previously... as I used it with auto mode.

However I am learning slowly now, but before learning manual settings I want to be able to know how to show auto mode with this camera setup. So here is my question:

I wonder is there any settings which would allow me full automation with full auto focus and by saying full auto focus I mean:

- Take a scene which has a person or ant object in it - hold the shoot button pushed. Camera takes the center point as a primary focus so if it's pointer to an object or person it's being focused. In case it's panorama focus applied to all view.

I know it depends on camera and lense, but it seems that both parts are compatible with auto focusing.

At the moment I need to physically change focal point on the lence (using lence spinner) all the time, can it be automatical?

Some settings I have at the moment:

- Body: Nikon D750
- Lense: Nikon AF-S 18-35mm f/3.5-4.5G IF-ED
- Lense focus: M/A
- Body focus (not sure if it's correct param name): AF
- Shooting mode: Auto
- Focus point (again not sure about this): AF-A

Comment: I can't say that I understand the question, but lens zoom cannot be automated.  And AF-A will NOT necessarily use the center point. Single Point AF will use the center point, if it and the center point are selected. Read the manual about Auto Focus Mode (see Index).

Comment: Yes, my lack of knowledge lead me to this question... I was thinking that focal length is affected with auto focus (not like zoom level) but it appears it's not, I am correct? I had my local length set to such level that close object where blurry and I expected autofocus to fix this...

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your distinction. Zoom of course changes focal length, but just focusing hardly does (can't say precisely zero, but focal length change is virtually zero).   Re Close objects blurry:  Depth of Field is the "range" or "depth of the focus zone, which is affected by aperture or subject distance or focal length.  http://www.google.com/search?q=depth+of+field

Comment: I think part of the problem here is technical terms. There is a thing called 'trap-focus' which will fire the shutter when an object appears in a pre-selected focus point. But you still have to select the focus point. If that is what you want, I'd change the question title to something like "How to use Trap Focus technique on a Nikon DSLR"

Answer (score 1):

The D750 has a 51 point AF system. You can manually choose an individual focus point yourself, choose a group of focus points, or let the camera decide entirely for you.

There are lots of good videos available online that can give you more information.

Here is a good basic video which describes the D750 Auto Focus system: [Nikon D750 Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nVTTH-FiwRc)